# silverlight WCF not working on internet

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I've created a WCF for my VS2010,C# silverlight app, I consume it without any problem on my local host, but when I upload it in my remote server, it doesn't work! what is my problem? I have upload two XML files (cross domain) beside my SVC file, but there is still no luck, what I'm missing?

Comment: A million things. Start by first ensuring that the commincation is is taking places and that all the protocol messages are non errored. Wireshark is your friend.

Comment: of course I've previously used WCF for my silverlight apps, but I cannot remember anything special, I've tested on successfully on local host, so I thing WCF has no problem and there my be some problems regarding my web deployment process, what is wireshark?

Comment: Wireshark is protocol sniffer. This is how I would debug this. 1 Ensure that all communications are not failing. If not investigate on side where comms is failing.

Comment: excuse me, what do you mean by comms? this is my SVC address:http://hightecdev.com/email.svc, it seems ok, I should try wireshark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your service more carefully (from the link your provided above), you see that the error speaks volumes. It even shows you what you need to do to solve it!

In your `web.config`, add another endpoint to publish metadata. The `mex` endpoint is so your clients can get to know the inner workings of your service.

`<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />`

and under your service behaviors element set:

`<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />`

**EDIT:** Though having said that your service still shouldn't work when you host it locally if you don't publish any metadata. Can you be a bit more descriptive about your scenario? Are you hosting your service in IIS? Which binding are you using? Is your service duplex?

Answer (score 1):

Need configure client config ("ServiceReferences.ClientConfig") for accessing in internet. Please change a endpoint address, change a "localhost" name and port to real site domain name.

Should work.